# postMessage независимо от протокола родителя (http/https)

Tags: javascript, iframe, cors

Мой скрипт встраивается на целевые сайты. Мне нужно сделать postMessage в iframe с другим доменом. Дело в том что я за ранее не знаю с каким протоколом(http или https) загружен сайт. По этому из за несовпадения протоколов возникает ошибка

```
frame.postMessage(data, 'https://framedomain.com') - выдаст ошибку если родительский сайт http
frame.postMessage(data, 'http://framedomain.com') - выдаст ошибку если родительский сайт https
```

Можно как-то указать домен без протокола, чтобы работало в обоих случаях?

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```js
// Для своего домена
var protocol = document.location.protocol; // http: или https:
// Для фрейма
var protocol = frame.contentDocument.location.protocol;
```